# Problem when trying to hide a column using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to hide a column as well as other elements when my page is printed, and in order to do that I have a print style sheet, everything works fine, except for the column I want to make disappear, the strange thing is that my stylesheet works in IE, but it didn't in Mozilla and Chrome; why's that?

HTML code

```
   <col width="10%" class="art-editcolumn"/>
```

and here's the CSS  class:

```
.art-editcolumn
{

   display: none;

}
```

Hope you can help me out with this.

Answer (score 3):

The display CSS property is [not allowed for the col tag](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_col.asp). Only background, width and borders. So the standards based browsers are simply ignoring it.

Answer (score 1):

See the following entry for the `<col>` tag: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_col.asp

You will note that only ONE attribute is supported in Firefox: 'width'

Also from that reference, the only CSS styles you can apply are 'background', 'width' and 'border':

> Add the style attribute to the `<col>`
>   tag, and let CSS take care of
>   backgrounds, width and borders. These
>   are the ONLY CSS properties that work
>   with the `<col>` tag.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: and what should I do then? do I have to repeat  the style for each cell, for each row??

Comment: Well you can't actually use the `display:none;` styling... Assuming the tag is where it belongs (inside a table) apply the style to the whole table...